# SiteMapPath Populated

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemappath, system.web.ui.webcontrols

How on earth is this SiteMapPath1 being populated? I have checked everywhere. I don't expect an exact answer just some ideas how it could be getting populated.

Front end

[image]

Back end

[image]

After page is loaded
[image]

The issue I am having is the breadcrumb is displaying an extra node and I have no idea why only discrepancy between my page and all the others what is is inherited. I've checked the data base I've checked all related pages how would one find out where the SiteMapPath gets its hierarchy?

I just want the hierarchy to be correct for some reason my page shows it is a child of another page when it isn't. Maybe there is a way to hide the previous node on my page alone. Should be Home: Email Notifications not Home: Optimized Duty Schedule: Email Notifications. Any ideas would really help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment by [Albert D. Kallal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10527/albert-d-kallal):

> there should be a file called Web.SiteMap - that's what drives the SiteMapPath control that is dropped into each page that you want that breadcrumb list. It is not maintained automatic, but maintained by you. So YOU have to maintain that Web.SiteMap, and put what pages you want into that file. You THEN drop a SiteMapPath control onto each form that you want that site map list.